# (2m-1)th Moments of GARCH(1,1) Process

Tags: garch, moments

I am currently studying the 2mth generating moment function of a regular GARCH(1,1) process which is given by Bollerslev (1986) as

$$\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t^{2m}] = a_m\bigg[\sum \limits_{n=0}^{m-1} a^{-1}_n\mathbb{E}[\epsilon^{2n}_t] a^{m-n}_0\binom{m}{m-n}\tau(\alpha_1, \beta_1, n)\bigg]\bigg[1 - \tau(\alpha_1, \beta_1, m)\bigg]^{-1}. $$

According to him, the (2m-1)th moment doesn't exist because of symmetry reasons, that is, if the 2mth moment existst then $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon^{2m-1}] = 0$.

My question: Why is that? Where is the symmetry?